# Unable to store text in SFML 2.4

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using sfml library for some sort of graphic work and I want to store the text that I have entered using keyboard but it shows an error
 please tell me how it is possible:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
   string s="";
   sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 200), "Ludo",sf::Style::Default);
   window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
               if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                {
                   window.close();
                }
               else if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::TextEntered)
               {
                   s += event.type.unicode;
               }
           }
          window.display();
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

the error is:

> sf::Event event, expression must have a class type

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
s += event.type.unicode;
```

`event.type` is a field describing the type of event (you've used it in the case checking above).

What you then tried is accessing a member `unicode`, which obviously fails, because `type` is not a class or struct here. What you actually want is the field `sf::Event::text`, which is a struct.

As such, this line would have to look like this:

```
s += event.text.unicode;
```

Comment: @ALIHAMZABASHIR The way you do should do the trick, you might have to manually construct a string object to append though.